# Understanding HTML5 Canvas Element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am read tons of documentation about save/restore canvas states, but still confused with next [example](http://jsfiddle.net/LUnu7/1/).

```
function draw() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

    // save default state
    ctx.save();

    // draw new arc with new settings
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#bfb';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#999';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(50, 50, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    // restore default state
    ctx.restore();

    // save default state again
    ctx.save();
    // draw line with new settings
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
    ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
    ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
    // restore default state
    ctx.restore();

    // save default state third time
    ctx.save();
    // draw round circle with new settings
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#999';
    ctx.arc(100, 100, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#bfb';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    // restore default state
    ctx.restore();
}

draw();
```

My logic in code comments, but result absolutely not expected. First circle has a settings from line. Circles should have different style from line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not good at canvas just yet but with some basic learning I think 
You are missing  `ctx.beginPath();` before starting to draw path.

```
function draw() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

    // save default state
    ctx.save();

    // draw new arc with new settings
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#bfb';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#999';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(50, 50, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    // restore default state
    ctx.restore();

    // save default state again
    ctx.save();
    // draw line with new settings
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
   ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
     ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
    // restore default state
   ctx.restore();

    // save default state third time
    ctx.save();
    // draw round circle with new settings
    ctx.beginPath();    /* ** THIS is missing in your code ** */
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#999';
    ctx.arc(100, 100, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#bfb';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    // restore default state
    ctx.restore();
}

draw();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LUnu7/3/)**

**[SOURCE](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/)**

Comment: Great. I was looking for a problem where there was none. Thanks, that's works.